# How to insert an embedded picture?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

`xlApp.activesheet.Pictures.Insert(strImagePath)` inserts pictures into a spreadsheet as a linked picture. If I send the spreadsheet out of our network the images fail.

How can I place an image as an embedded image?

I am also calling this method from Access.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

you can use the shapes.addpicture method

```
activesheet.Shapes.AddPicture Filename:="C:\test\desert.jpg", linktofile:=msoFalse, _
            savewithdocument:=msoCTrue, Left:=0, Top:=0, Width:=100, Height:=100
```

Comment: Thanks @JosieP! This works great. Now I am trying to assign it to a Shape object so I can make some adjustments. I did `Dim shpPic as Shape` and `Set shpPic = xlApp.activesheet.Shapes.AddPicture ...` and I get a type mismatch error. Any idea why?

Comment: based on the xlApp part I guess you're automating from another app-does that app have Shape objects? if so use `dim shpPic as Excel.Shape`

Comment: Hi @JosieP, yes I'm calling from Access. I can't use `Excel.Shape` because I don't want to have a reference to the Excel library because I have users with a large range of systems. I declared my excel instance like this: `Dim xlApp as Object`  `Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")` So I tried `Dim shpPic = xlApp.Shape` and that gives me "User-defined type not defined" error. Any ideas?

Comment: you've gotta declare as Object if you're late binding excel

Comment: Oh ok, thanks. I'm not very familiar with late binding. So would I declare like this: `Dim shpPic As Object`  `Set shpPic = xlApp.Shape`? I tried that and it said "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: no you `Dim shpPic as Object` then use the `set shpPic = xlapp.activesheet.shapes.addpicture...`

Comment: Note that you can set the required Width and Height parameters to -1, which then maintains the height and width of the original image!

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can set the required Width and Height parameters to -1, which then maintains the height and width of the original image!

```
Activesheet.Shapes.AddPicture Filename:="C:\image.jpg", LinkToFile:=msoFalse, _
        SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, Left:=0, Top:=0, Width:=-1, Height:=-1
```

http://excelmatters.com/2013/11/25/default-picture-size-with-shapes-addpicture/

(Added as another answer to increase visibility as I've struggled with this problem for ages and haven't found this solution documented anywhere else.)

Answer (score -1):

```
Activesheet.Shapes.AddPicture Filename:="C:\image.jpg", LinkToFile:=msoFalse, _
        SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, Left:=0, Top:=0, Width:=-1, Height:=-1
```

**this works, maybe the following code can help someone too (it helped me)
this is how you select the image you've just added:**

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes(ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count).Select
```