# Insert (and then reference) a picture into Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to insert a picture into a worksheet using VBA, that I can later reference by name (to for example delete, or hide).

I can insert the image using code similar to the below:

```
 ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture Filename:="image.jpg", linktofile:=msoFalse, _
        savewithdocument:=msoCTrue, Left:=10, Top:=20, width:=100, Height:=50
```

However, I'm struggling to assign the picture to a shape (or other object) so that I can name it and later refer to it. e.g.

```
Dim shp As Shape
set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture Filename:="image.jpg", linktofile:=msoFalse, _
        savewithdocument:=msoCTrue, Left:=10, Top:=20, width:=100, Height:=50
shp.name = "myPicture"

... some code ...

ActiveSheet.Shapes("myPicture").Delete ' or similar code to later delete the image
```

However, I'm getting a syntax error on the `set shp = ...` line

I've also tried with: `Dim shp As Excel.Shape`, `Dim shp As Object` as per the comments in SO post: [VBA to insert embeded picture excel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17110977/1448678) but still get the syntax errors.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need parentheses when returning a value from a method:

```
set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(Filename:="image.jpg", linktofile:=msoFalse, _
        savewithdocument:=msoCTrue, Left:=10, Top:=20, width:=100, Height:=50)
```