# Insert a picture into existing excel file

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, excel, file

i'm new to vb.net, and i want to open an existing excel file, and insert an image to a specific cell, such as 'C16' for exemple.

It's been three days and i'm searching about this topic, but what i found was just creating a new excel file and insert a picture to it.

Anybody can help?

Comment: The way of inserting a picture into a cell for an existing file shouldn't be different from the way for a new one. Once you opened it, just add your image like you would do. Look at this link: http://www.visual-basic-tutorials.com/WriteToExcel2007.php. Once you did this, if you still can't, show us some code and we will point you what is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've already found a solution:
please find it below

```
                    workbook = APP.Workbooks.Open(filepath)
                    worksheet = workbook.Worksheets("name of the excel sheet")

                    worksheet.Visible = True
                    Dim pic1 As String = "picture path"
                    worksheet.Range("I51:I51").Select()
```

I51 is the cell where i want my picture

```
                    worksheet.PageSetup.Zoom = False
                    worksheet.PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1
                    worksheet.PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = 1
                    Dim opicture1 As Object
                    opicture1 = worksheet.Pictures.Insert(pic1)
```

Comment: In my test. It will insert the path of an image, not the image itself.

Comment: So I am using WorkSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(picPath, False, True, 0, 0, Width, Height) .

Answer (score 0):

The code can be used is like this:

`ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(pathForPicture & "\" & pictureName & ".jpg").Select 'Path to where pictures are stored`

For more reading from this site: [VBA to insert embeded picture excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17110425/vba-to-insert-embeded-picture-excel)

[How to insert a picture into Excel at a specified cell position with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12936646/how-to-insert-a-picture-into-excel-at-a-specified-cell-position-with-vba)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to provide my codes.

```
Dim picPath As String = "C:\..."
Dim _Left   = xlWorkSheet.Range(WorkSheet.Cells(i, j).Address).Left
Dim _Top    = xlWorkSheet.Range(WorkSheet.Cells(i, j).Address).Top
Dim _Width  = xlWorkSheet.Range(WorkSheet.Cells(i, j).Address).Width
Dim _Height = xlWorkSheet.Range(WorkSheet.Cells(i, j).Address).Height
WorkSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(picPath, False, True, _Left, _Top, _Width, _Height)
```

`picPath` is the path of the image you want to insert.

`(i,j)` is the index of the cell where you want to insert an image.