# MS-Word, VBA: Copy picture stored in an image control in a form to the document

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have an picture (jpg) stored in an image control in an embedded form in a word document. My goal is to copy this picture from the form to the word document by using a VBA macro.
Unfortunately I have found no way of achieving this.

Has anyone done this in the past and is willing to share his solution?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39521019/copy-picture-from-userform-to-spreadsheet. Just change the line that inserts the pic into the worksheet so it inserts it into the document. You will, of course, need to tell Word *where* to insert the pic.

Comment: Thanks, but this solves my problem only partially - I'd like to avoid the temporary file for confidentiality issues. Sorry for not mentioning this restriction in my initial question.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this ...

```
Sub CopyPasteImages()
    Dim cc As Word.contentControl, rng As Word.Range
    For Each cc In ActiveDocument.ContentControls
        If cc.Range.InlineShapes.Count > 0 And cc.Type = wdContentControlPicture Then
            cc.Range.InlineShapes(1).Range.Copy
            Set rng = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\EndOfDoc").Range
            rng.Paste
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```