# Insert Dynamically in Excel using image from server path

Tags: excel, vba, image, dynamic

I have code below to look for an image of a sku in a specific folder in our server and insert /autosize - but the issue i have is that if I send this spreadsheet to anyone else not on the server, they cannot see images. 
Can someone help fix this so it inserts the image dynamically? I believe this is what has to be done to place the actual image in the sheet rather than link-back when the sheet is updated/Opened. 
Or, how can I format this to send out and include images if they are not linked to the server? 
I have looked at other posts which refer to inserting dynamically but I cant get anything to work

```
Sub Imageupdate()
' inserts the picture files listed in col A into the workbook,
' and sizes and centers in col B

Const sPath       As String = "S:\Images\Casio\"
'Const sPath       As String = "C:\Users\shg\Pictures\shg"
Dim cell          As Range
Dim sFile         As String
Dim oPic          As Picture

For Each cell In Range("A2", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
sFile = sPath & cell.Text & ".jpg"
If Len(Dir(sFile)) Then
  Set oPic = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(sFile)
  oPic.ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue

  With cell.Offset(, 1)
    If oPic.Height > .Height Then oPic.Height = .Height
    If oPic.Width > .Width Then oPic.Width = .Width

    oPic.Top = .Top + .Height / 2 - oPic.Height / 2
    oPic.Left = .Left + .Width / 2 - oPic.Width / 2
  End With
Else
  cell.Select
  MsgBox sFile & " not found"
End If
Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA to insert embedded picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17110425/vba-to-insert-embedded-picture-excel)

Comment: I did find Dim xlApp as Object Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application") So I tried Dim shpPic = xlApp.Shape but is this what I need? Would I just paste after the section that resizes the image?

Comment: You're already in Excel - I'm not why sure why you're using `Set xlApp = CreateObject...` But in any case, if you're using [`Shapes.AddPicture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Shapes.AddPicture), `shpPic` is just a `Shape` - `Dim shpPic as Shape`.

Comment: Thank you. I am REALLY new to VBA, Would you mind letting me know the format for how I should add that above?

Answer (score 0):

Based on both answers from the question [VBA to insert embedded picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17110425/vba-to-insert-embedded-picture-excel), use [`Shapes.AddPicture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Shapes.AddPicture) (or [`Shapes.AddPicture2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shapes.addpicture2) if you want to compress the picture when inserting.)

- *LinktoFile* is `msoFalse`
- *SaveWithDocument* is `msoTrue`
- *Width* and *Height* are each `-1` to preserve the existing dimensions of the picture

---

```
Sub ImageUpdate()
' inserts the picture files listed in col A into the workbook,
' and sizes and centers in col B

Const sPath       As String = "S:\Images\Casio\"
'Const sPath       As String = "C:\Users\shg\Pictures\shg"
Dim cell          As Range
Dim sFile         As String
Dim shpPic        As Shape
Dim ws            As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet

With ws
    For Each cell In .Range(.Range("A2"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
        sFile = sPath & cell.Text & ".jpg"

        If Len(Dir(sFile)) Then
            Set shpPic = .Shapes.AddPicture(sFile, msoFalse, msoTrue, 0, 0, -1, -1)
            shpPic.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue

            With cell.Offset(, 1)
                If shpPic.Height > .Height Then shpPic.Height = .Height
                If shpPic.Width > .Width Then shpPic.Width = .Width

                shpPic.Top = .Top + .Height / 2 - shpPic.Height / 2
                shpPic.Left = .Left + .Width / 2 - shpPic.Width / 2
            End With
        Else
            cell.Select
            MsgBox sFile & " not found"
        End If
    Next cell
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Glad to help you! If it worked, feel free to mark the answer as accepted by clicking the check mark beside it.